# Can't understand GEOHAYSTACK index in pymongo, which index is the fastest?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have huge document and wanted to add index to the most queried field.
I tried all of the indexes provided by pymong and the fastest one proved to be GEOHAYSTACK.

This is how I would add indexes to the documents:

```
self.events.create_index([('target', TEXT)], name='target_index',
                         default_language='english')
```

To test the performance I just did 1000 queries with the field and measured which one performed better.

My question, is GEOHAYSTACK faster than TEXT and HASH indexes, or this is just error in the benchmark I did?

Comment: What does your actual query look like? The three index types you've mentioned (text, hashed, and geoHaystack) are all used for different purposes and are not directly comparable in terms of query parameters or results. You'd want to choose an appropriate index type based on your use case (text search vs hashed value vs geospatial).

Answer (score 0):

Performance measurement on computers is highly delicate because it can be influenced by numerous factors (CPU&RAM power, system usage, IO to name a few).
The result you obtained on your computer is not necessarily the same as another would come up with. So it is quite possible that another index will come out top if you run the experiment again.
From the description of [geohaystack](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/2d/) I understand it's best used for geographical data points. How the heck it turned out to be the best for your datastructure I don't know. But without seeing the schema of of `events` it's impossible to say because the structure is different to your example of a text index:

```py
db.coll.createIndex( { <location field> : "geoHaystack" ,
                       <additional field> : 1 } ,
                     { bucketSize : <bucket value> } )
```

Since I quickly described the geolocation index, I also want to sprinkle a few words about the other two. Mostly information from the linked sites and topped with an opinion.

Speaking of which ([TEXT hash](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/)), I would assume runs the slowest because string comparison is generally expensive. And since it advocates its support for querying in multiple languages, it seems to be

Lastly [hash index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-hashed/) can only search for exact matches. Since mongodb applies a function to the field value and saves the result, it can only determine if there is a match or none. Even if the field values only slightly differ, the hash result will be completely different (given the hash function causes few collissions). This behaviour might give an edge compared to the other two. However, your example showed it can turn out differently after all.

I hope this helps you choose the right index type for your datastructure. I suggest to use the one that fits your use case the best.